# Search Variable and copy-paste an Offset cell from it

Tags: excel, vba

**Hi,
Thank you for your help in advance! I will present my issue in the next lines:**

**1.** I have a list of a hundred key words in Sheet1.

**2.** For each one of them I have to find, if it is present in a list in Sheet2.

**3.** If it is not, it has to proceed to the next key word.

**4.** If it is present, it should copy the cell that it is three positions to the left from the found one.

**5.** And paste in Sheet1 to the right of the keyword.

```
Sub Alaba()

Dim x As Object
Dim y As Variant
Dim z As Variant

Sheets("#CoT.military refresh").Activate
Range("c3").Select

Do
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select

Set x = ActiveCell

Sheets("Copy of CoT HQ").Select
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Find(What:=x, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Set y = ActiveCell

If Not y Is Nothing Then
y.Offset(0, -3).Copy
Sheets("#CoT.military refresh").Activate
Selection.Find(What:=x, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

End If

Loop Until x = "a"

End Sub
```

This is the code I have come up so far, but it gives me an error in this line:

```
ActiveCell.Paste
```

I would be really glad, if you could help me finding a solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check if the Selection.Find gives you an error? In that case you can see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm, is a great page explaining that.

You can also have problems with combined cells (but I think this is not your problem, no?

And if I were you, I will not use OffSet, for me is clearer this:

```
dim row as integer
 row=Selection.Row
row=row-3
Cells(row,5).Select
Selection.Copy
'Column 5 is E
```

Hope it could help you